# HTML text in box and in front

Tags: html

I have an assessment from my professor and i need to create a website the same way my professor made it. [image: the website of my professor] i am almost done but the last thing that i couldnt figure out how to do is the boxed review from my professor i tried it but it was not as i hoped to be [image: my html website with the weird result]. everything is working fine only the boxed review doesnt work and i dont know how to fix it. Can someone help me please?

my code:

```
<!--
Assignment 12 (HTML Semantics ();
-->

<!-- Make changes to the code below -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Assignment-12</title>
    <style>
      .boxed {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="boxed">
      <aside><p></p></aside>
      <h2>Reviews</h2>
      <article>
        <h3>Would not recommend</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto,
          accusantium!
        </p>
        <p><small>1/5 stars</small></p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h3>These cats are crazy</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod,
          aspernatur!
        </p>
        <p><small>2/5</small></p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h3>Awful service</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, neque!
        </p>
        <p><small>1/5</small></p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Toys</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Dogs</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Cats</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Toys</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Adopt</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Birds</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1>Welcome to the petstore</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
        laborum ipsa sint reprehenderit amet expedita architecto itaque
        consequuntur quas laudantium?
      </p>
    </main>
    <hr />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Adopt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2>Cat Adoption</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error beatae at
      tenetur quo, non ratione nulla! Voluptates repudiandae ab hic.
    </p>
    <img src="/images/cats.png" alt="Images of Cats" />
    <p>
      Doordeweeks voor 22:00 besteld, morgen in huis. Weekend besteld, maandag
      in huis.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fixed position, z-index, background, border and box-shadow`

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes on the style.
For better uses, you can look [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/)

```
 <style>
  .boxed {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 40%;
  }
</style>
```

Also, the div you give boxes class does not include all the elements and it provides a better view if you fix it.